# segmentation fault in C in linux

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run this C programming in linux ubuntu.I am getting an error segmentation fault(core dumped).I am trying to read a text file containing lines in the following format:

```
key01 value01
key02 value02
key03 value03
```

Here is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ARY 50
int main() 
{
    int i=0;
    int numProgs=0;
    char* lines[MAX_ARY];
    char line[40];
    int j;
    char search_key[1000];
    int position=6, length=5, c = 0;
    char str[10];
    int ret=0;
    char* token;
    char* my_key;    

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("client1.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file)!=NULL) 
        {
            //check to be sure reading correctly
            //printf("%s", line);
            //add each filename into array of programs
            lines[i]=malloc(sizeof(line));
            strcpy(lines[i],line);
            i++;
            //count number of programs in file
            numProgs++;
        }

    //check to be sure going into array correctly 
    for (j=0 ;j<numProgs+1;j++) 
        {
            //printf("%s", lines[j])
            ;
        }

    printf("Please enter your search:");
    scanf("%s",str);


    for(i = 0; i<numProgs; i++)
        {    
            // Gettng the univ names from the list
            token = strtok(lines[i]," ");

            /* walk through other tokens */
            while( token != NULL )
                {
                    ret=strcmp(str, token);
                    printf("str=%s\t token=%s ret=%d\n", str, token, ret);
                    token = strtok(NULL," ");

                    if(ret==0)
                        {
                            //now token should be my required token, so break here
                            break;
                        }
                }
            if (ret == 0)
                break;
        }

    printf("Required substring is: %s\n", token);
    //send(token,to-server1); 
    fclose(file);
    return 0;

}
```

I am unable to fix the error.

Comment: Your code has potentially a lot of reasons that may wxplain a segmentation fault, it's basically a potential for a buffer overflow in many places, the most notable one is `scanf("%s", str);` because `sizeof(str) == 10`, and also `malloc(sizeof(line))` might be `malloc(strlen(line) + 1)` instead, if you just want to copy the read bytes, change to `scanf("%9", str);` and check if the problem persists.

Comment: If you haven't learned to use gdb yet, this would be a good time to start.  If you compile with debugging symbols enabled, gdb can tell you exactly were the segfault occurred, and let you inspect the relevant variable values to see what went wrong.

Comment: Check return code of `fopen()` (in your case it's `file` variable). `fopen()` can return `NULL` in case of errors. Trying to use `file` variable (pointer actually) further may lead to seg fault (on dereferencing this pointer). Just remember to always check return codes of library functions / system calls before going further.

Comment: show your input and output.

Comment: how many lines are in your text file?

Comment: the text file will contain either 4 or 12 lines

Comment: I have changed to malloc(strlen(line) + 1) and scanf("%9", str) . Even then it is giving me segmentation fault.

Comment: To further tack on to @JimLewis's comment (which I completely agree with), this is where you can read the core file.  Before you run your program, make sure you set (if using linux) `ulimit -c unlimited` and then after running the program (if it crashes) run `gdb ./[your program name] core`.  This will allow you to run a back trace using `bt` and see exactly where you crash & burned!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this version of your code (actually its the same as yours except two small changes)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ARY 50
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int numProgs=0;
    char* lines[MAX_ARY];
    char line[40];
    int j;
    char search_key[1000];
    int position=6, length=5, c = 0;
    char str[10];
    int ret=0;
    char* token;
    char* my_key;

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("client1.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file)!=NULL)
    {
        //check to be sure reading correctly
        //printf("%s", line);
        //add each filename into array of programs
        lines[i]=malloc(sizeof(line));
        strcpy(lines[i],line);
        i++;
        //count number of programs in file
        numProgs++;
    }

    //check to be sure going into array correctly
    for (j=0 ;j<numProgs;j++)
    {
        printf("%s", lines[j]);
    }

    printf("Please enter your search:");
    scanf("%s",str);


    for(i = 0; i<numProgs; i++)
    {
        // Gettng the univ names from the list
        token = strtok(lines[i]," ");

        /* walk through other tokens */
        while( token != NULL )
        {
            ret=strcmp(str, token);
            printf("str=%s\t token=%s ret=%d\n", str, token, ret);
            token = strtok(NULL," ");

            if(ret==0)
            {
                //now token should be my required token, so break here
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ret == 0)
            break;
    }

    printf("Required substring is: %s\n", str);
    //send(token,to-server1);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;

}
```

**the changes :**

1- `for (j=0 ;j<numProgs+1;j++)` ---> `for (j=0 ;j<numProgs;j++)`

2- `printf("Required substring is: %s\n", token);` ---> `printf("Required substring is: %s\n", str);` (if you try to print token it will just print null)

**conclusion:**

Your code works fine, please verify that the file "client1.txt" exists in the same directory as your .c file. Generally it's a good habit to test after calling function such (fopen, open, malloc ... etc) if everything went fine